# Using Views to filter images based on taxonomy of page node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have many image files with taxonomy associated with them. I have page nodes using the same taxonomy vocabulary. I want to create a Views block that filters the images displayed based on what that page uses for that vocabulary.

Fake example:

I have a page that is tagged with `carrots` and `broccoli`.
I have image files tagged with the same terms. I want to place a Views block on the page and have that view only show images tagged with the same terms.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a views block.
Under Contextual filters, add Content: Has Taxonomy Term ID
Provide Default Value -> Taxonomy Term ID from URL
Tick on 'Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks' and tick your proper vocabulary.

Comment: So to clarify as I am new to Drupal. The `Under Contextual filters, add Content: Has Taxonomy Term ID` part of your anwser, there is no option specific to that text. Would it that be if the field on both items is called `Vegetables` it would say `Content: Vegetables (field_vegetables)`. Is that the filter I should select

Comment: Add contextual filter..From the dropdown select Content: Has Taxonomy Term ID. In the configuration settings of this filter select Provide Default Value under WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE.
Tick on 'Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks' and tick your proper vocabulary(in your case maybe vegetables).